# Line spacing in systeme

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, systeme

I'm working on a document where I need to increase the spacing between lines of text, but I want to keep the line spacing in arrays or systems unchanged. I've tried using the `baselinestretch` command with a value greater than `1`, say `4`, but this affects the spacing in arrays as well. To address this, I set `arraystretch` to `0.25`, which restores the standard spacing in arrays. However, I'm facing an issue when using the `systeme` package – the line spacing remains elevated, and I want it to be set back to normal (similar to arrays).

How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{4}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.25}

\begin{document}

\systeme{x+y=0,2x-y=1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the spacing in arrays to be normal, you need 0.25 rather than 1

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Though this unfortunately does not fix this issue.

Comment: That’s a different issue. Sorry, I’m on the phone. If nobody chimes in, I’ll have a look later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\systeme` command uses low level TeX constructs that depend on `\baselineskip`, but don't take into account `arraystretch`.

There is no method implemented in the package, but a simple patch works. Here I use a less dramatic spread factor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstretch{2}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}% actually, the reciprocal of the spread factor

\catcode`_=11
\xpatchcmd{\SYS_systeme_i}
 {\begingroup}
 {\begingroup\linespread{1}\selectfont}
 {}{}
\catcode`_=8

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\lipsum[2][1-2]
\[
\systeme{x+y=0,2x-y=1}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]